# TypeScript sort an array of nested objects

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and struggling to solve problems. Say, I have an data.

```
data: [
{ 
    id: 123, name: Toyota,
    detail: [
            {id: 15, desc: 'K1', value: 7 },
            {id: 16, desc: 'B5', value: 4 },
    ] 
},
{ 
    id: 127, name: Cammry,
    detail: [
            {id: 17, desc: 'K1', value: 9 },
            {id: 11, desc: 'B5', value: 3 },
    ] 
},
{ 
    id: 177, name: Honda,
    detail: [
            {id: 12, desc: 'K1', value: 8 },
            {id: 13, desc: 'B5', value: 3 },
    ] 
}]
```

And I have fuction sort by "value" with "desc"

```
public Sort_Item(desc, type) { 
if (type === 0){
    // sort order ascending     
}
else{
    // sort order descending
}}
```

I want sort value with "desc" and order type ascending or descending.
EX: this.Sort_Item("K1", 0) // param 'K1' and order ascending
and result is

[image]

Thanks all!